# Anime about a couple of kids who find a giant robot that is orange and white

Tags: story-identification, anime, mecha

I remember watching it in middle school. It has a couple of kids who find this giant robot that is orange and white. I don't remember much of the plot, but I do remember that during the show the robot evolves and they find a purple version hidden in a cave system. Any help? It's not a very well-known anime.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this? Also, did you watch it on TV or online? If on TV, then in which country and language?

Comment: If anyone correctly identifies this, you can mark their answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].